# PHP include and require losing variables

Tags: php, include, require, require-once

I have the following two files. The first a long php script, the second just a handful of variables:

**File1.php:**

```
<?php
...
function abc()
    {
        ...
        include "File2.php";
        echo "$x $y $z";
        ...
    }
?>
```

**File2.php:**

```
<?php
$x=1;
$y=2;
$z=3;
?>
```

None of the variables appear inside my function in the `echo` statement - using xdebug I step through it including the second file, each variable appears correct, but when it leaves `File2.php`, it loses all the variables.  Why would that be?

I've stripped the first file to get rid of everything but the above - and it works fine. I'm not sure where to start looking in the thousands of lines of code for something that could be causing this problem to happen.

I've even tried using `require`/`require_once` - same problem...

Has anyone come across this before or have any thoughts how to debug it?

Comment: `include File2.php;` is pseudo code I take it. If it isn't, that should read as `include 'File2.php';`

Comment: Do you call the function?

Comment: Fred-I rekeyed it hence accidentally omitted the apostrophes. 
Elias-Yes I call the function-using xdebug I set a break point at the first line and step through it all-when it enters the include file, it picks up all the variables, and loses them all when it exits the file

Comment: Do you have display_errors turned on? (always do so when developing & testing code). If those variables are not defined in function scope, PHP will complain about it.  `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: The variables are you are including in the function scope so it makes sense they are not available outside the function. http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php If that is an incorrect interpretation of the issue please provide a reproducible version of the code.

Comment: Chris, I'm not using the variables outside of the function-just inside the function. I can't provide a reproducible version of the code as it is thousands of lines long. I've reduced it to the core process - which isn't working as there is a problem somewhere in the other lines but I'm not sure where to start looking.

Comment: Unfortunately, this code is reproducible (working, at least for me), so without anything else to go on, it's impossible to say what is wrong with it.

Comment: Michael, PHP does error if I try to use the variables saying they are uninitialised or Undefined variables. Xdebug picks them up as uninitialised too.

Comment: I get this code working too Rasclatt - However when it sits in a larger function in a script comprising thousands of lines of methods for a given class, it doesn't work - I can't see what would or could be interfering or causing it problems.

Answer (score 0):

**File2.php**

```
<?php
    $x=1;
    $y=2;
    $z=3;
?>
```

an if you need to call `file2.php` inside `file1.php`, you have to use `include()` function as well

---

**Correct way of using it**

```
include ('File2.php'); //correct
include 'File2.php'; //correct
include File2.php; //wrong
```

---

**File1.php**

```
<?php   

    function abc()
    {
        include ('File2.php');
        echo "$x $y $z";
    }
?>
```

Comment: I've tried both 
include ('File2.php'); //correct
include 'File2.php'; //correct
I have exactly the same problem. As I said above, the missing apostrophe is just a typo.

Comment: ya. that's i mentioned all possible uses of `include` function

Comment: That code does and has always worked - my question is that the function is a method in a class file, which has dozens of other methods and thousands of lines of code of which these lines are a part. These lines in that context are not working and I don't know how to determine what is causing the problem - some ideas in terms of what to maybe look for or how to try to pin down the problem would help.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this :-
File1.php:

```
<?php
include ('File2.php');

echo $x;
echo '<br>';
echo $y;
echo '<br>';
echo $z;
?>
```

File2.php

```
<?php
    $x=1;
    $y=2;
    $z=3;
?>
```

Comment: Earlier I had got this skeletal code working too. However when it sits in a larger function, one of many many methods in a class, in a script comprising thousands of lines of code, it doesn't work - I can't see what would or could be interfering or causing it problems or where to try starting to debug what's causing the problem. That was my original question.